# Compile C file , run it and write header with CMAKE

Tags: c, header, cmake, code-generation

I need to run a simple `main.cpp` program which writes a file `header.hpp` which I need to include in other CMAKE target?

How is this best achieved? (platform independent?)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_generate_a_source_file_during_the_build.3F
This fully answers the question!